# How can I set the seek point in a VideoView or otherwise quickly end playback?

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is there a way to set a video in a `VideoView` to the final second of its duration? Or trigger the `onCompletionListener` by code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VideoView.seekTo(int milisec)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#seekTo%28int%29)

Attention, the unit of the parameter is in millisecond.

```
myVideoView.seekTo(myVideoView.getDuration())
```

If you have access to the instance of the class who implement the onCompletionListener, you can just manually call the function.

But I think it's quiet a bad idea; a callback should never be fired manually.

Comment: would you tell me why this is a bad idea? :)

Comment: Because MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener is a listener. The callback onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) should be only fired automatically when the video is over.

Comment: i want to overwrite `MediaController`'s next button to jump to the end of the video and not just 5 or 10 seconds forward. still a bad idea?

Comment: If you jump to the end of the video by using VideoView.seekTo(int mili), I guess the callback will be fired

Comment: i accepted your answer. but maybe for other readers it might be a good idea to either remove the `bad idea` comment or explain your opinion. btw: it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick view of the `VideoView` api there is a `VideoView.seekTo(int msec)` method. I would use that but then you will need to know the video length. That may be depending on your code, i'm not familiar with that. You might look it up or open a new question.